# Can fractions be written with a one under them and can problems be solved this way

Tags: fractions

How would you write $\frac{a}{0.1}$?

Are either of these ways acceptable?

$$
\frac{\frac{a}{1}}{\frac{\frac{1}{10}}{1}} = \frac{a}{1} \times \frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}}
$$
or 
$$
\frac{\frac{a}{1}}{\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{a}{1} \times \frac{10}{1}
$$

Comment: You might be interested in learning to post mathematical expressions using [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.  In any case dividing by one-tenth is the same as multiplying by ten, right?  If you are studying fractions at less than a high school level, it would be helpful to your Readers to say so.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are correct and yield $10a$ in the completely simplified form.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are correct, but it's very important for you to know the
following expressions. Here's some good examples:

---

**Note: Do the parentheses before the division**

## $$\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{4}{5}}=\frac{(\frac{2}{3})}{(\frac{4}{5})}= \frac{5}{6}\tag1$$

---

## $$\frac{\frac{0.4}{2}}{2\frac{3}{5}} = \frac{(\frac{0.4}{2})}{(2\frac{3}{5})}=\frac{\frac{2}{5}\times\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{13}{5}}=\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{\frac{13}{5}}=\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{5}{13}=13 \tag2$$

---